# can internal crystal for microcontroller work in twi interface?

Tags: microcontroller

I was thinking since clock timing is provided by master microcontroller to rtc/sensor etc.We can use any crystal (including internal) on microcontroller and there will be no timing problem.

is this true?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need precise timings, you can use internal RC oscillator.
Note, there is no 'internal crystal', it is only R-C circuit like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_oscillator).
I don't know any MCUs with integrated quartz crystal, there is only some RTC ICs (like Maxim DS3231) feature.

If you use SPI or I2C (TWI), bus timings may have any values, and you may use simple internal RC-circuit.
If your device use UART or will measure any timeouts, you should examine oscillator parameters of your MCU. Which oscillator should be used, depends on required accuracy, parameters, provided by MCU, and some other options (like device working temperatures).